# VB.net Set x,y,z values from text file into separate arrays

Tags: arrays, vb.net, text

I have been trying to find out how to do this for days now, so I am finally asking how.  I am newish to programming.  Here is my problem.

I am trying to extract x,y,z coordinates from a text file arranged as such:

x,y,z
x,y,z
x,y,z
etc.

I need to be able to extract the x column into an array, the y into an array, and the z into an array.  I learned how to pull it into a string, and how to split for every line, but I don't know how to split after each comma and separate them.

Answer (score 1):

The `String.Split` function will split text by a selected character into an array of Strings.

```
Dim values As String() = line.Split(","c)
Dim x As Integer = Integer.Parse(values(0))
Dim y As Integer = Integer.Parse(values(1))
Dim z As Integer = Integer.Parse(values(2))
```