# VB.NET - How can I parse a string with X Y Z values out of order?

Tags: vb.net, cartesian-coordinates

I´m trying to write a parser that reads large files, try to locate X Y Z values on lines that can contain more registers than only X Y Z (Like M codes and other commands to drive CNC machines).

I was successful in reading the code and separating data from each line. Now I´m stuck in a function that is supposed to analyze this treated block and look up for X Y and Z coordinates, not necessarily in this order, not necessarily containing all 3 axes.

The good news is that the axis name always preceeds the value of the given axis, so even if the line may have XYZ out of order (ZYX or YZX for example), or just X and Y without Z, the letter of the axis is always preceeding the value.

I need to extract the value of each axis and treat it, and the save it back. I can do the treat and save it back, but I´m clueless about how I can write a function that can parse X Y and Z even if they are out of order or with a missing register (i.e., Z is not present in the block, or Y, or X).

I only want to extract XYZ values in the string ***strNewLine*** passed to the function ***ParseAndChangeNCBlocks***, and ignore everything else in the line.

This is my code:

```
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

    Public DebugMode As Boolean = True

    Sub Main()

        Dim path As String = "C:\8888.nc"

        ' This text is added only once to the file.
        If File.Exists(path) = False Then

            ' Create a file to write to.
            Dim createText() As String = {"Hello", "And", "Welcome"}
            File.WriteAllLines(path, createText)
        End If

        ' This text is always added, making the file longer over time
        ' if it is not deleted.
        Dim appendText As String = "This is extra text" + Environment.NewLine
        File.AppendAllText(path, appendText)

        ' Open the file to read from.
        Dim NCProgram() As String = File.ReadAllLines(path)
        Dim NCBlock As String
        For Each NCBlock In NCProgram
            Console.WriteLine(CleanUpAndSeparateBlocks(NCBlock))
        Next
    End Sub

    Function CleanUpAndSeparateBlocks(ByVal NCBlock As String) As String
        Dim strBlockLength As Integer = 0       'Comprimento do bloco
        Dim strNewLine As String = ""           'Linha tratada
        Dim strMotionText = ""                  'Parte anterior ao comentário
        Dim strCommentText = ""                 'Comentário do bloco
        Dim intCommentStartIndex As Integer = 0 'Index inicial do comentário
        Dim intCommentEndIndex As Integer = 0   'Index final do comentário
        Dim intCommentLength As Integer = 0     'Comprimento do comentário

        strNewLine = NCBlock.Trim               'Remove blanks esq/dir
        strNewLine = strNewLine.ToUpper         'Converte pra maiúsculas

        intCommentStartIndex = strNewLine.IndexOf("(") 'Armazena o início do comentário
        intCommentEndIndex = strNewLine.IndexOf(")")   'Armazena o fim do comentário

        If intCommentStartIndex > -1 And intCommentEndIndex > -1 Then    'Se um comentário for detectado
            strBlockLength = strNewLine.Length                           'Captura o comprimento do bloco
            strCommentText = strNewLine.Remove(0, intCommentStartIndex)  'Remove a string anterior ao seu início
            strCommentText = strCommentText.Trim                         'Remove blanks esq/dir
            strMotionText = strNewLine.Remove(intCommentStartIndex, strBlockLength - intCommentStartIndex) 'Separa a parte anterior ao comentário
            strMotionText = strMotionText.Trim                           'Remove blanks esq/dir
            strMotionText = strMotionText.Replace(Chr(32), "")           'Remove blanks do meio da string
            strNewLine = strMotionText + Chr(32) + strCommentText        'Forma o novo bloco

            If DebugMode = True Then                                     'Se depuração estiver ativa
                MsgBox(strNewLine)                                       'Exibe a nova linha 
            End If

        Else                                                             'Bloco não contém comentários
            strNewLine = strNewLine.Replace(Chr(32), "")                 'Remove blanks do meio da string
        End If

        ParseAndChangeNCBlocks(strNewLine)                               'Converte coordenadas para interpolação cilíndrica

        Return strNewLine
    End Function

    Function ParseAndChangeNCBlocks(ByVal NCBlock As String) As String
        Dim XCoord As Double = 0
        Dim YCoord As Double = 0
        Dim ZCoord As Double = 0


        Return NCBlock
    End Function

End Module
```

In the end of the funcion ***CleanUpAndSeparateBlocks*** I call ***ParseAndChangeNCBlocks***. The last is the function where I´m supposed to analyze the string that has been passed to the function, and start the extraction of each axis.

I thought about using this to extract each value: Found it here: [VB.net Set x,y,z values from text file into separate arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044341/vb-net-set-x-y-z-values-from-text-file-into-separate-arrays)

```
Dim values As String() = line.Split(","c)
Dim x As Integer = Integer.Parse(values(0))
Dim y As Integer = Integer.Parse(values(1))
Dim z As Integer = Integer.Parse(values(2))
```

However, this solution assumes that XYZ are always in this order, and that they are not preceded by the axis name, which in my case always occur, but the axes may be presented out of order or even be absent from the line.

Here some test data to be used within "C:\8888.nc"

```
%
o8888(usinagem helice)   
g00g21g40g80g99 
g49 
g69.1 
m05 
m46 
m246
m45 
n10 g28u0.
n20 g28w0.
n30 g28h0.
n40 g330 
n50 (#5222=0)
n60 g7.1y0. 
n70 m69
n80 m46
n90 g98g18 
n100 m45

n110 (desbasta perfil - parte 1)

n120 t1025
n130 g361b0d0 
n140 g43h25.
n150 g54
n160 s3714m13 

n170 g01z440.#0.x13.258y-276.689f10000.
n180 g19w0h0
n190 g1 y-276.689
n200 g7.1y188.
n210 g01z376.

n220 goto 2843850 (jump to contour finish - using cutcom and cylindrical interpolation)

n230 g03 x7.809 y-271.766 r87.496
n240 g01 x7.804 y-271.758 f1485.
n250 y-271.756
n260 x7.846 y-271.75
n270 x7.902 y-271.743
n280 x7.974 y-271.734
n290 x8.064 y-271.725
n300 x8.175 y-271.713
n310 x8.311 y-271.701
n320 x8.477 y-271.688
n330 x8.68 y-271.673
n340 x8.927 y-271.656
n350 x9.232 y-271.639
n360 x9.613 y-271.62
n370 x10.097 y-271.6
n380 x10.69 y-271.581
n390 x11.284 y-271.566
n400 x11.879 y-271.554
n410 x12.055 y-271.551
n420 x12.449 y-271.553
n430 x12.837 y-271.573
n440 x13.207 y-271.61
n450 x13.55 y-271.664
n460 x13.856 y-271.731
n470 x14.118 y-271.812
n480 x14.328 y-271.903
n490 x14.48 y-272.002
n500 x14.571 y-272.107
n510 g03 x13.711 y-272.547 r1.606 f10000.
n520 x7.804 y-271.758 r4.1
n530 g01 x7.78 y-271.714 f1485.
n540 z100. x7.779 y-271.711
n550 x7.835 y-271.7
n560 x7.898 y-271.687
n570 x7.972 y-271.674
n580 Z200. x8.052 y-271.659
```

I only want to extract the X, Y, Z values of each line, in whatever the order or combination (XYZ, or Z, or YX, or Y, etc) they appear. Can someone shed some light in how I can structure the function ***ParseAndChangeNCBlocks*** to do that?

Many thanks!

Comment: In the line "n170 g01z440.#0.x13.258y-276.689f10000.", what is the significance of the "#0." part?

Comment: I suggest that you use the Decimal type for the numbers instead of Double so that there is no chance of a number being not quite exactly what was written. [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) explains why in detail.

Comment: Hi Andrew, #0 is just a replacement mistake... I left it there so I could test the parser with an error like that....

Answer (score 2):

This is easy to do with *regular expressions*. You just need to work out a regex which will match a number, then precede it with x, y, or z as needed:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Module1

    Function ExtractAndOrderXYZ(s As String) As String
        Dim num = "([+-]?[0-9.]+)" ' regex to match a number

        Dim xMatch = Regex.Match(s, "x" & num, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
        Dim yMatch = Regex.Match(s, "y" & num, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
        Dim zMatch = Regex.Match(s, "z" & num, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

        Dim orderedString = ""

        If xMatch.Success Then
            orderedString = xMatch.Captures(0).Value
        End If

        If yMatch.Success Then
            orderedString &= yMatch.Captures(0).Value
        End If

        If zMatch.Success Then
            orderedString &= zMatch.Captures(0).Value
        End If

        Return orderedString

    End Function

    Sub Main()
        ' Following line outputs x13.258y-276.689z440.
        Console.WriteLine(ExtractAndOrderXYZ("n170 g01z440.#0.x13.258y-276.689f10000."))

        ' Following line outputs y-276.689
        Console.WriteLine(ExtractAndOrderXYZ("n190 g1 y-276.689"))

        ' Following line outputs x7.809y-271.766
        Console.WriteLine(ExtractAndOrderXYZ("n230 g03 x7.809 y-271.766 r87.496"))

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

In the regex `([+-]?[0-9.]+)`, the parentheses indicate what to capture. `[+-]?` means an optional sign, `[0-9.]+` means one-or-more digit or decimal point.

Comment: Thanks Andrew - Yes I had to ask because I´d never come up with such elegant solution... Many thanks everyone!

Comment: this solution is much better than mine. if you want to avoid the load of a regular expression you can use `IndexOf` with checking not less than 0 and `Substring` and  `Val()`

Comment: @bansi The Val() function would not be suitable if there could be another component which started with "E" which happened to follow one of x,y,z - Val() would take the E to represent exponential notation. Also (AFAIR), the framework will realise that a regex is being used a lot and optimise for it.

Answer (score 0):

try this to get X value from a line. you can do the same for y and z

```
function getX(byval line as string) as string 
 Dim val as String = ""

 if(line.indexOf("X") >= 0) 
      val = line.subString(line.indexOf("X") + 1)
      val = val.subString(0, val.indexOf(" ")
end if
return val 

end function
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this. comment in code.

```
Function ParseAndChangeNCBlocks(ByVal NCBlock As String) As String
    Dim XCoord As Double = 0
    Dim YCoord As Double = 0
    Dim ZCoord As Double = 0
    Dim values As String() = NCBlock.Split(" "c)
    'iterate through each item and check what char it starts with
    For Each value As String In values
        If value.StartsWith("x") Then
            XCoord = Val(value.Substring(1))
        ElseIf value.StartsWith("y") Then
            YCoord = Val(value.Substring(1))
        ElseIf value.StartsWith("z") Then
            ZCoord = Val(value.Substring(1))
        End If
    Next
    'Do all your calculation here for the x y z 

    'don't know what return you want
    'this just puts it back in the order
    Return String.Format("x{0} y{1} z{2}", XCoord, YCoord, ZCoord)
End Function
```

Note: if you expect upper and lower case letter for xyz then you should use comparison like the following.

```
value.StartsWith("x", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Comment: The coordinates are not always separated by spaces, e.g. the line starting with n170 in the example.